# Inspect Element in Google Chrome - Hide Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can't seem to figure out what I changed in my Inspect Element tool, but now when I use it, it's always popping up with the console underneath it. How do I set it so the console part is hidden when inspecting an element? I can manually drag that portion of the tool down so I have a larger html portion of the tool, but it's a pain in the rear. It didn't used to do this, and just started last week.

[Here's a screenshot](http://prntscr.com/31q6xp) showing what part I'm talking about. The portion of the picture inside the red box with the red arrows pointing at it is the part I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide it again by clicking the following button:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch. I must have pressed that on accident. It's been really annoying having to drag it down every time I inspect something.

Answer (score 4):

You can also open and close it by pressing Esc.